# Implications of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,\ Y,\ Z >0\ $ random variables such that $X=YZ$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent. If I have the following two relationships:
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=c],\ \forall c\ge0 $$
and $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y\ge c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y\ge c]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y\ge c],\ \forall c\ge0 \label{1}$$
Does the first imply the second or vice versa or no implication is present?

For the first,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X|Y\ge c]&={1 \over \mathbb{P}(Y\ge c)}\int_0^{\infty}\int_c^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}f_Y\ dy\ dx\\
&={1 \over \mathbb{P}(Y\ge c)}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]f_Y\ dy\\
&={1 \over \mathbb{P}(Y\ge c)}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=y]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=y]f_Y\ dy\\
&\not={1 \over \mathbb{P}(Y\ge c)^2}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=y]\ f_Y\ dy\ \int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Z|Y=y]f_Y\ dy\\
\end{align}$$
For the second implication I get:
$${\mathbb{P}(Y\ge c)}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]f_Y\ dy\\=\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=y]\ f_Y\ dy\ \int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Z|Y=y]f_Y\ dy\\$$ 
Which gives:
$$\int_c^{\infty}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]f_Y\ f_Y\ dy\ dl\\=\int_c^{\infty}\int_c^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=y]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=l]f_Y\ f_Y\ dy\ dl\\$$
Which implies $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=c],\ \forall c\ge0 $.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Can you find any example where the first statement is untrue (whether or not the second statement is true)?

Comment: No, because $\mathbb{E}[YZ|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[cZ|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=c]$ by definition. So if we say that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\ \mathbb{E}[Z|Y=d]\ \forall c,d\ge 0$ then this will imply the second relationship?

Comment: All statements imply true statements, though this is not particularly informative.  But true statements do not imply false statements